# В чем разница между перегрузками оператора []? c++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, индексация, индексы

Есть код:

```
double& operator[](int index);
double operator[](int index)const;
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём разница?

Comment: В первом случае возвращается ссылка, т.е. вы можете изменять значение, что-то вроде 

    `a[i] = 5;`

Во втором же случае, применимом для *константных* объектов, возвращается *значение*, т.е. его можно использовать в каких-то выражениях и т.д., но это копия чего-то, хранящегося внутри, и что остается неизменным. Как и сам объект.

Comment: константный объект будет вызывать оператор с атрибутом `const` справа. А не константный - другой. возвращаемый тип `double&` - это ссылка, а `double` - значение.